# Outputting succesive addresses of members of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address

[image]

I drew this for a better understanding. In the PC's memory there are succesive memory zones with length of 1 byte ( the green ones ). They can be grouped for representing bigger data ( as an `int` in our example ).

What i want to add to this picture is that the green squares are succesive addresses like `0x000000` followed by `0x000001` etc. Then the addresses from `arr` are jumping by four like `0x000000` and the next one would be `0x000004` ( because an `int` in this care is `4bytes` ).

**The code_1**:

```
int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};

int *p = arr;

cout << p << endl;
cout << ++p << endl;
cout << ++p << endl;
cout << ++p << endl;
```

**The output_1**:

```
0x69fedc
0x69fee0
0x69fee4
0x69fee8
```

**The code_2**:

```
char arrr[5] = {'1','2','3','4', '\n'};

char *ptr = arrr;

cout << &ptr << endl;
cout << &(++ptr) << endl;
cout << &(++ptr) << endl;
cout << &(++ptr) << endl;
```

**The output_2**:

```
0x69fed0
0x69fed0
0x69fed0
0x69fed0
```

**The problem**:I expect in `output_2` i expect that the addresses would be `0x69fed0`,`0x69fed1`,`0x69fed2`,`0x69fed4`

Comment: Ask yourself: Does `int foo = 42; ++foo;` change the address of the of `foo`, or `foo`'s value?

Comment: Do you mean the address of each element?

Comment: Yes! sorry for my mistake. The question is how to output the addresses for the `char` array as if i want to do the same like i did with the `int` array, it does not work because it outputs me `1234`, `234`, `34`, and `4`

Comment: `cout << static_cast<void*>(++ptr) << endl;` is what you want.  Since `ptr` holds the address, you just print it's value.  Just doing `cout << (++ptr) << endl;` wont work though as it could be treated as a c-string.  So you cast to a `void*` so you `cout` prints the address the pointer holds.

Comment: Thank you a lot. From your answer : `static_cast<void*>` what chapter shoud i search for to better understand this? I mention that i rarely meet the `< >` writing

Comment: That should be covered in the chapter(s) about templates.

Comment: I have another question: if the array is the one in the first example, why printing `cout << arr` and `cout << &arr` outputs the same ?

Comment: Because of array to pointer decay.  The address of the array is also the address of the first element so so `arr` and `&arr` are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are displaying the **address of the pointer** instead of the address stored in the pointer:

```
char *ptr = 0;
std::cout << &ptr;       // address where the pointer is placed
std::cout << (void*)ptr; // address managed by the pointer = 0

++ptr;

std::cout << &ptr;       // this value never changes
std::cout << (void*)ptr; // Now this value should be 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I will search for `void*` because i'm not familiar with it!

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu `void*` is an anonimous pointer. `cout` has an overload when using `char*` that prints the text *inside* the pointer but when using `void*` the address will be printed